# Grails redirect to URL in an interceptor -- API Gateway Architecture

Tags: redirect, grails, microservices, grails3, api-gateway

## Context:

I'm designing an API gateway for some microservices. The idea is:

I intercept all the incoming requests in a global interceptor, analyze them for accessibility based on some permissions and finally use a simple `redirect` to call the actual URL. For example, I'm doing the following at one place:

```
if(permAction && authorizationService.hasPermission(user, micro, permAction)) {
            if(microName != "umm"){
                log.info("Successfully Authorized. Forwarding request to: ${micro?.ipAddress}${req}")
                redirect(url: "${micro?.ipAddress}${req}", params: params)
                return false
            }
            log.info("Successfully Authorized. Forwarding request to: ${req}")
            return true
}
```

For simple `GET` requests, it works fine.

## Questions

I'm having some problems with this approach.

1. When I hit the API from the front end, through my gateway, it gives a `302` and finally gives a `200` whether the original API exists or not in the original microservice. It gives a `404` if directly hit. What's happening?
2. <strike>There is an error in the console saying `preflight cors` disabled. What is that? It wasn't there without redirection.</strike>
3. <strike>I want all the `GET`, `PUT` and `POST` requests to redirect to various microservices.</strike>As far as I searched, redirect in grails only support a `GET` request.
4. Is there any other (better) approach to achieve the same? <strike>Maybe `RESTClient` on the server side or something similar.</strike>

Some of these questions have been partially answered but not in this context. Any insights about the problems in the context would be great.

Complete interceptor file is given [here](https://github.com/saqibahmed515/UMM/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/com/ef/umm/SecurityInterceptor.groovy). This repository contains the whole project for the Grails API gateway.

## Update :  4:30 pm

Resolved **question 2** by allowing `OPTIONS`in the `Allowed-Methods` on the server side.

## Update: 11:12 pm

For **number 4**, I implemented a rest client at the gateway backend. It works fine as far as functionality is concerned. However, with rest client at the backend, client requests gateway, which in turn requests the microservice, gets the response and gives it back to the client. This sort of two-way involvement of gateway is costly. This also **resolves** question **number 3** by the way.

**Is there any other better solution for a gateway in some other language or technology which can provide robustness out of the box?**

Comment: In my opinion #4 would give you the greatest level of programability with your gateway and the potential for the highest security with your micro services. I'd focus on a solution that approaches the problem in that way.

Comment: As for number 4, I implemented a rest client at my backend. It is working but the problem is with the overhead it causes. I was thinking on the lines of redirection in such a way that a single request connects the client to the microservice getting the gateway out of the picture.